# Ignore negative value

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I tried to search this problem and unlucky to solve.

I have a generated report using the `rdlc`, now, I want to sum all the positive numbers not including the negative in *`rdlc` coding way*.

```
     Credit
     ------
          3
          3
          3
          3
          3
          3
          2
         -3
         -2
     ------
Total:   20
```

So, the main point is **ignore** the **negative** and **sum** the **positive** numbers. so far this what I have tried and this not the solution of my problem.

```
=IIF(Fields!creditUnit.Value > 0, Sum(Fields!creditUnit.Value), 0)
```

Anybody can help me?

**UPDATE:**

This was my temporary solution, since my generated report is good for only one page. I create a parameter for **Total**

```
var total = creditsList.Where(c => c.HasValue && c.credit > 0).Sum(c => c.credit.Value);
var totalParam = new ReportParameter("total", total);
```

I hope that one of you guys can help me in what would be the solution in *rdlc coding way* to sum all the positive numbers.

**UPDATE:**

I included the [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) because the way the coding of `rldc` is `VB` syntax.

Comment: This does look particularly **not** like C#...

Comment: i apologize, i will modify. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!creditUnit.Value > 0, Fields!creditUnit.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Odd, I've used it before.  I wish "#Error" was more descriptive.

Comment: by the way, i used the .net 4 client profile version.. unfortunately your answer is not the solution.. anyway, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know its to late but this will work for me

if column have only integer then following expression can be use.

**`=Sum(IIf((Fields!creditUnit.Value>0), CInt(Fields!creditUnit.Value), 0))`**

But for decimal or integer and decimal (both) following expression can be use.

**`=Sum(IIf((Fields!creditUnit.Value>0),CDbl(Fields!creditUnit.Value),0.0))`**